# Eliminating a row index and its rows completely from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am writing a python script with the the following dataframe in pandas:

```
dog   dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
      jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
fox   dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
      jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
jumps dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      over    1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
over  dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
      jumps   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
the   dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0
      fox     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      jumps   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      over    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
```

Here I want to eliminate any row containing the word 'fox' in either first or second level row index so the new dataframe becomes:

```
dog   dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1
      jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
jumps dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      jumps   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      over    1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
over  dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      the     1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0
      jumps   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
      over    1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
the   dog     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0
      the     1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      jumps   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
      over    1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0
```

It would be advantageous if I can eliminate multiple words like this in a single query. For example 'fox' and 'over'. I have tried using a combination of [df.xs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and df.drop but nothing seems to work properly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['dog', 'dog', 1], ['dog', 'fox', 1], ['dog', 'the', 1],
                   ['fox', 'dog', 0], ['fox', 'fox', 0], ['fox', 'the', 0],
                   ['jumps', 'dog', 1], ['jumps', 'fox', 1], ['jumps', 'the', 1]],
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

df = df.set_index(['A', 'B'])

#            C
# A     B     
# dog   dog  1
#       fox  1
#       the  1
# fox   dog  0
#       fox  0
#       the  0
# jumps dog  1
#       fox  1
#       the  1

def remover(df, lst):
    return df.drop(lst, level=0).drop(lst, level=1)

df = df.pipe(remover, ['fox', 'dog'])

#            C
# A     B     
# jumps the  1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have column names (colname) defined, this might work:

```
df = df.loc[(df.index != 'fox') & (df.colname != 'fox')]
```

or, if it's a multi-indexed data frame, by resetting the index, you can do:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
df = df.loc[(df.index != 'fox') & (df.colname != 'fox')]
```